# Extract format dates from dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe in python containing various dates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2020-01-27 welcome ! offer","Space ! offer 2020-02-27","new | 2020-03-27"],
                   "A_item":[2, 8, 0],
                   "B_item":[1, 7, 10],
                   "C_item":[9, 2, 9],

                   })
```

and i need to get this as a result

| Date | A_item | B_item | C_item | Extracted Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-27 welcome ! offer | 2 | 1 | 9 | 27-01-2020 |
| Space ! offer 2020-02-27 | 8 | 7 | 2 | 27-02-2020 |
| Space ! offer new 2020-03-27 | 0 | 10 | 9 | 27-03-2020 |

Does anybody know how to extract them

Comment: Please show the code you wrote to solve this and what problem you had with it. You tagged the question already with "regex", so you have an idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
def extract_date(x):
    pattern = "[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+"
    match = re.findall(pattern, x)
    return match[0]

df["new_column"] = df["first_colum"].apply(extract_date)
```

`first_column` is the source column.

Then you should get the output below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks i a have updated my code based on previous comment

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Extracted Date']=df['Date'].str.extract(r'([\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{4})|\)')
```